# Python locks that go away when process dies

Tags: python, locking, ipc

Is there any locking interface for Python that automatically breaks the lock when the process dies? I was under the impression that sysv ipc allows for that, but I'm still trying to figure out the details.

What I expect from the interface:

- lock / release functions
- working between different processes on Linux
- automatic unlock when the process holding the lock dies
- forced lock breaking on timeout (not necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply locks to a file using `fcntl.lockf` or `fcntl.flock`. That seems to meet all your criteria. Or do you need something that doesn't require a system call every time you want to lock or unlock?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a try ... finally block to release a lock.
e.g.

```
try:
    #do stuff
except Exception:
    pass
finally:
    #release lock
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `Lock` objects in the built in `multiprocessing` package. I'm not sure whether the lock will automatically unlock when a process is garbage collected, but you could always subclass `multiprocessing.Process` like this:

```
class MyProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ipc_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        # ...
        return
    def __del__(self):
        self.ipc_lock.release()
        return
```

if you need to unlock if an exception is fired then put that in the (overridden) `run` method.